# Ruby Script 13 digit regex syntax

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the regex to work that I found in a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092691/regex-for-field-to-contain-13-digits)... so I put the script together but I'm getting some syntax errors. please have a look for me.

```
require 'yaml'

f =  File.open("file.txt")
content = f.read

r = Regex.new(^(\d{13})?$)
ids = content.scan(r).uniq
puts YAML.dump(ids)
```

This script strips 13 digit numbers from a databump in a text file. Here is the error I'm getting..

```
ID_Script.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '^', expecting ')'
r = Regex.new(^(\d{13})?$)
           ^
ID_Script.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
r = Regex.new(^(\d{13})?$)
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a string to Regex constructor

```
r = Regex.new("^(\d{13})?$")
```

or use a regex literal

```
r = /^(\d{13})?$/
```

Comment: Hi Sergio, Thx for the info. The numbers are between quotes "123456789012". Will that regex be able to strip out the numbers?

Comment: Yep, it will be able to do that (and leave the quotes intact).