# add multiple scripts and styles on theme option does not work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add multiple scripts and style on my custom theme option via functions.php, I declare it like this

```
function cyb_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script',get_template_directory_uri().'/theme-options/jquery.js');
    //Enqueue styles and scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script',get_template_directory_uri().'/theme-options/script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style',get_template_directory_uri().'/theme-options/style.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cyb_admin_scripts');
```

but unfortunately only one is added like jquery only. Any help, suggestions, clues, recommendation please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to use a regular expression to remove blank lines from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369642/javascript-how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-remove-blank-lines-from-a-string)

Comment: check `console` for errors and try to fix those.

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading scripts using `wp_enqueue_script`, first parameter must be your unique name for handle this script later, if needed. In your case you are using name `'my-script'` twice. I never did this, but suppose, that one script overwrites other in some point.

So try to use unique names for all your scripts and styles.

[wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Also in your `script.js` you use `jquery` as dependance, but this will load `jquery` library that comes with WP, so you don't need to include your own `jquery` from `theme-options` folder