# Recognizing empty lines in a text?

Tags: java

Im taking input from a separate file which currently has one paragraph. Im storing every word in the paragraph into a list and then iterating over each of them using this:

for (String word: words)

However, this iterator goes over each WORD. If I have two paragraphs in my input file which are separated by an empty line, how do I recognize that empty line under this for-loop iterator? My thinking is that iterating over words is obviously different from going over lines, so Im not sure.

Comment: Is it possible for you to only deal with a paragraph at a time? If so, you could just read up to the empty line, deal with that paragraph, then read in the second paragraph *after* you're done with the first.

Comment: You act surprised that the iterator goes over each word, yet that is specifically what you've told it to do. Can you give a more complete example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

An empty line follows the pattern:

```
\n\n       
\r\n\r\n
\n -whitespace- \n 
etc
```

A word following the pattern

```
-whitespace-nonwhitespace-whitespace-
```

Very different patterns. So looping over something using the definition of a word will never work.

You can use Java scanner to look at a file line by line.

```
public class LineScanner {

  public List<String> eliminateEmptyLines(String input) {
    scanner Scanner = new Scanner(input);
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine) {
      String line = scanner.nextLine;
      boolean isEmpty = line.matches("^\s*$"); 
      if !(isEmpty) {
        output.add(line);
      }
    }
    return output;
  }
}
```

Here's how the regex in `String.matches` works: [How to check if a line is blank using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012788/how-to-check-if-a-line-is-blank-using-regex)
Here's the javadoc on `Scanner`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html