# what is the regular expression for a blank line?

Tags: regex, r

http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/grep.php

I've looked through the chart for a regular expression that corresponds to a blank line, but I just can't seem to find it. I've tried `\\n` but that means a newline, not that it's necessarily blank.

**example**:

```
string = c("Precedence: bulk", 
  "List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:zzzzteana-unsubscribe@yahoogroups.com>", 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit", 
  "", 
  "Martin A posted:", 
  "Tassos Papadopoulos, the Greek sculptor behind the plan, judged that the", 
  " Mount Athos monastic community, was ideal for the patriotic sculpture. ", 
  " ", 
  " As well as Alexander's granite features, 240 ft high and 170 ft wide, a",
  "planned", 
  "---------------------", 
  "So is this mountain limestone or granite?")
```

So lines 4 and 8 are empty, and I want `grep` to return those indices.

Comment: I'm not sure what the synatax for R is, but you could  try `^\s*$` which is 0 or more whitespace characters, which should capture blank lines.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't quite work.

Comment: What does the data look like.  Is it a vector?  Data.frame etc.  Please make this reproducible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012788/how-to-check-if-a-line-is-blank-using-regex

Comment: I tried `grep("^s*$", string)` but that didn't work. `string = c("Precedence: bulk", "List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:zzzzteana-unsubscribe@yahoogroups.com>", 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit", "", "Martin A posted:", "Tassos Papadopoulos, the Greek sculptor behind the plan, judged that the", 
" Mount Athos monastic community, was ideal for the patriotic sculpture. ", 
" ", " As well as Alexander's granite features, 240 ft high and 170 ft wide, a", 
"planned", "---------------------", "So is this mountain limestone or granite?")` So lines 4 and 8 are empty, and I want grep to return those indices.

Comment: `grep("^\\s$",string)` works.  You need the double-backslash in R to escape the backslash in the regexp ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R you need to escape the backslash so it should be `^\\s*$`. You can also use `^[[:space:]]*$`.

```
grepl("^[[:space:]]*$", c("", "  ", "\t"))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
grep("^[[:space:]]*$", string)
# [1] 4 8
```