# How can I check if a string is empty including hard return?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Currently I have a function that checks if a string is empty or not, but it does not detects if I there is a new line

```
export const isStrEmpty = function(text: string): boolean {
  return !text || text.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
};
```

I tried adding `\n`, it doesn't work

```
export const isStrEmpty = function(text: string): boolean {
  return !text || text.match(/^ *\n$/) !== null;
};
```

Is there a way I can make this function detects if there is a new line in the string?

Comment: Check to see if `text.length === 0`

Comment: You can use this `!!text` , as it would convert the string into boolean `true` if it's length all except 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it the regex way:

```
^\s*$
```

where `\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r \n \t \f \v])

A similar Question was asked here: [How to check if a line is blank using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012788/how-to-check-if-a-line-is-blank-using-regex)

Comment: next time, please just mark as a duplicate, no need to repost identical answers

Answer (score 0):

```
return letter.trim()==='' ? true : false;
```

Please try this.