# Text inbetween Digit and BlankLine

Tags: java, regex

How to get text inbetween Digits and Blankline Using Java 
I Used Regex which shows

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
            String index out of range: -1
```

Code Here:

```
            List<String> file = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), 
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
               for(String v:file)
               {
                  if(v!=null)
                  {
                     String answer = v.substring
                     (v.indexOf("//d")+1,v.indexOf("\\n"));
                    System.out.println(answer);
                  }
               }
```

What is wrong with my regex?

```
      My File  :text.txt
                    fruits
                  1 Mango
                    Apple
                    Blank line
                    Veg
                  2 Onion
                    Tomato
                    Blank line
```

My Excepted Output is :

```
                    Mango
                    Apple
                    Onion
                    Tomato
```

But I Got Exception

Note : This File is Sample.And original File is Too Long
       I mean blank line not new line

Comment: I think perhaps something's wrong with you `v.indexOf("\\n")`

Comment: Why do you expect `Apple` and `Tomato`? They seem to be on separate lines with no digits.

Comment: that comment i used to get upto first index of newline after number

Comment: `"//d"` should be `"\\d"`

Comment: yes but apple and tomato are inbetween number and blank line as i want to get text inbetween digits and blank line

Comment: So.. in your file, there are 8 separate lines? And you want to print everything between a number and a blank line? Not the end of a line? (There is usually a newline at the end of every line in a file)

Comment: my file is too long. i just posted my file sample..and yes i want to print everything in between number and blank line and not end of line

Comment: Sorry, I meant you should write in your Question that you do not mean newline, you mean the blank line :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below regex to achieve your purpose:

```
(\d+ )([\w\W]+?)(?=((\r\n|\n|\r)$)|(^(\r\n|\n|\r))|^\s*$)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`(\d+ )`** - Represents first capturing group matching 1 or more digits followed by a space character. **If space characters are more than one then you can use the + quantifier.**
>
> **`([\w\W]+)`** - Represents second capturing group matching every [character and non-character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#:%7E:text=With%20a%20%E2%80%9Ccharacter%20class%E2%80%9D%2C,one%20out%20of%20several%20characters.&text=A%20character%20class%20matches%20only,character%20class%20does%20not%20matter.) classes.
>
> **`(?=)`** - Represents positive look-ahead asserting any empty lines appearing in front.
>
> **`((\r\n|\n|\r)$)|(^(\r\n|\n|\r))|^\s*$`** - Matches any empty line present in the test String. For better insights; please read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39282395/7571182) answer.

[image: Pictorial representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/fuqO0V/3)

**Implementation in java:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Main {
  private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d+ )([\\w\\W]+?)(?=(?:(?:\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)$)|(?:^(?:\\r\\n|\\n|\\r))|^\\s*$)", Pattern.MULTILINE);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("folder", "data.txt");
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

    while (matcher.find()) {
      sb.append(matcher.group(1) + "\n"); \\ \n to separate every match in a newline.
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://repl.it/@mAndY80SS/SampleRunCode)

Comment: thanks for ur time..i am sorry i mean blank line and not the new line.for me this code runs but empty console as you used the space regex(i thing)

Comment: but your data.txt file does not have any empty line.i mean blank line

Comment: that was my falut i wrongly mentioned new line instead of blank line